# Viewing custom objects of DWG in viewer

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge

I am a newbie developer. I am able to view the uploaded dwg in viewer but for some reasons I am not able to view custom objects/ entities from the dwg file. Please suggest a workaroud to view the custom objects in viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service does not support custom objects other than the Autodesk ACE/ADT ones. This is because the Model Derivative service do not have your Object Enablers to do the extraction (geometry & properties).
The workaround in this case is to use the [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/) which offers a LMV extraction operation. In this service you can provide your custom object enablers for AutoCAD to do the extraction properly. Find an example [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer)